# Why does Node parent process use the subprocess on message event to handle messages sent by child process

Tags: node.js, ipc

Here's the example from the nodejs document.

parent.js

```
const cp = require('child_process');
const n = cp.fork(`${__dirname}/sub.js`);

n.on('message', (m) => {
  console.log('PARENT got message:', m);
}); // Why use n the subprocess here????

// Causes the child to print: CHILD got message: { hello: 'world' }
n.send({ hello: 'world' });
```

child.js

```
process.on('message', (m) => {
  console.log('CHILD got message:', m);
});

// Causes the parent to print: PARENT got message: { foo: 'bar', baz: null }
process.send({ foo: 'bar', baz: NaN });
```

I can understand the child process uses `process.on('message'...)` and `process.send(..)` to receive and send messages to the parent process.

But why does the parent process to use an instance of the subprocess to receive messages from the child process `n.on('message'....)`. Should it be `process.on('message'...)` just like the child process?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent will communicate with many children. while child will communicate with one parent.

Comment: Thanks. It's just this API is not very intuitive.